# Confusion of Hbase drop table

Tags: hbase

In the Hbase command line,when I wanted to create one table for example table1,but couldn't success,the output was:"The table already exists".So then I drop it,but still could not success,said:"the table exist".so I was very confused,when I issued list command I couldn't find the table1,but when I list hadoop hdfs directory I could find it.
So could you please help find the reason.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

In order to drop a tables in Hbase you need to disable it first.Try this in your hbase shell.

```
hbase(main):001:0>help 'drop'
```

You will get to know the reason.

```
Drop the named table. Table must first be disabled. If table has
more than one region, run a major compaction on .META.:

hbase> major_compact ".META."
```

What i think in your case the table is not completely dropped it still exits in .meta. .
Please correct me if i am wrong.